# When does the closure of intersections not equal the intersections of closures (in $\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: real-analysis

I have already proved that $ \overline{S \cap T} \subseteq \overline{S} \cap \overline{T} $. I now need an example of when equality fails, but cannot come up with anything.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Consider two open intervals with a common endpoint, but are disjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** 
Take $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$. What are their closures? And their intersection? The closure of their intersection?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S,T \subset \mathbb{R}$ be given by
\begin{align*}
S &= \mathbb{Q}\\[4pt]
T &= \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}